# How to simulate Click in cronjob?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cron, automation

I'm using a web service to transfer files from ftp to dropbox. I want to update the version in dropbox every week. Right now I have to go into the service and manually click the 'transfer now' button every week.

I'd like to create a cron job or other automated solution that runs every week, logs into the service and clicks on a set of buttons with an interval of 60s between each button (to give the service enough time to start the action).

The buttons are nothing but a div with an id and an actual click on it triggers a JS listener.

The way I was going to approach this was to write a cURL script in php that loads the page and then tries to do the action that occurs when the button is pressed (i.e. triggers the listener). It's not easy though and before I spend too much time on it, I'd like to know if anyone can think of a simpler approach?

The basic structure of the process should be:

- Runs automatically every week (e.g. on a LAMP server or using a web service)
- Logs into service (simple form triggering a POST request)
- Clicks on all the buttons with class 'buttonNow' and waits x amount of seconds between the clicks
- Ideally it would send some kind of confirmation once the task has been completed

Comment: Why don't you install the drop box service on that machine, and then just set up a cron job once a week to copy files from your FTP folder to the local dropbox folder? Because what you're proposing above, to be frank, is not going to happen.

Comment: Why doesn't cron job just do the file updates directly? Your concept doesn't make any sense

Comment: You could do something like this with phantomjs/casperjs or something heavier like selenium but this seems like a rather backwards approach to the process. Is it not possible to simply do the transfer from ftp to dropbox using just ftp and/or ftp and local file tools?

Comment: @DalHundal - It's a shared hosting environment - I can't install any additional software like dropbox.

Comment: @tomburger - try using the dropbox API then. Attempting the method you proposed will be fraught with complications and you will end up crying in the corner.

Comment: @EtanReisner - thanks for your input. I'm using a service that does exactly this (load data from ftp into dropbox). The only problem is that I need to trigger the transfer manually. If you know of a framework to do the transfer myself, that would help and as you pointed out, a much more elegant solution!

Comment: @DalHundal - do you know of any framework that makes working with the dropbox API easier than just out of the box?